# Wordpress format issues - archives and spacing

Tags: php, javascript, html, wordpress

So hopefully you guys can help me solve this riddle as I am lost at how to fix this issue.

A couple months ago we updated our website and our blog, in doing so I copied over the database and all the old posts. However, for some reason posts older than 2+ years are having format issues. Instead of spacing correctly, the entire blog is bunched up. You can see an example below.

[Example](http://www.changecompanies.net/preview/blog/?m=200605)

Now looking at the post I can see that there is no html to signify paragraph breaks and it generally looks like a text document with only a couple  tags in there. I have been going through by hand on these posts adding  tags and the correct  tags where necessary, obviously this is EXTREMELY time consuming and as there are years of old blogs that need to eventually be updated, I was looking for a way to simplify this issue.

My theory, is that there was some wordpress plugin in place on the old site (I did not manage this) that fixed the format issues and displayed the posts correctly, however somewhere down the road it got fouled up.

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to fix or maybe even speed up this process?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Well after a few more hours of tinkering and research I think I found a way to make the process faster. I still have to edit some of the posts manually, but at least now it appears I don't have to add those `<br>` tags back in.

Here is the resource I found.  [PS Disable Auto Formatting](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ps-disable-auto-formatting/installation/)

And here is what I did to speed up the process.  I should **note** it is a good idea to **backup your Wordpress Database for doing this!**

1. Download the plugin and install it.
2. Activate the plugin
3. Go the plugin option screen and UNCHECK the box titled "content formatting" basically enabling it
4. Go down to the batch formatting and select the date from which the older posts started and check "Allow batch formatting"
5. Click Batch Formatting and the plugin will format your older posts putting in `<br>` tags where appropriate and spacing where appropriate.
6. Browse to one of the edited posts and you will see it looks all jumbled and strange, thats fine dont worry!
7. Now head to your plugins page and **DEACTIVATE** the plugin.  Go back to one of your posts after the plugin has been deactivated and you will see that the post is now formatted correctly!
8. Make any additional edits to the post(s) and hit **update**, and your older posts should now be fixed again.

This solution isn't perfect but it will save me time in the long run.

Thanks and good luck.